# Javascript Object Instances lose function access on Array Recall

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

I have the following code example :

```js
var cobj = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0,
  asdinit: function(x, y, w, h) {
    this.a = x;
    this.b = y;
    this.c = w;
    this.h = h;
  },
  adsfads: function(a, b, c, d) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
}

var c = new cobj.asdinit(1, 1, 1, 1);
var bigarray = []
for (t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
  var newobj = new cobj.asdinit(1, 1, 1, 1);
  bigarray.push(newobj);
}
for (t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
  var localobj = bigarray[t];
  localobj.adsfads(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

At the time of object creation - all functions are accessibly callable.  After and on recall from the array the functions are not available?

Answer (score 1):

you will want to re-write your code so that a function returns your objects.

```
var cobj = function() {
  return {
    a: 0,
    b: 0,
    c: 0,
    asdinit: function(x, y, w, h) {
      this.a = x;
      this.b = y;
      this.c = w;
      this.h = h;
    },
    adsfads: function(a, b, c, d) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;
    }
  }
}.bind(this)

vat cobjInstance = cobj();
var c = cobjInstance.asdinit(1, 1, 1, 1);
var bigarray = []
for (t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
  var newobj = new cobjInstance.asdinit(1, 1, 1, 1);
  bigarray.push(newobj);
}
for (t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
  var localobj = bigarray[t];
  localobj.adsfads(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `asdinit` and `adsfads` functions as constructors. The objects created from each construction only have `a`, `b` and `c` properties. They do not have any prototype methods.

I think what you're actually after is

```js
class cobj {
  constructor (x, y, w, h) {
    this.a = x
    this.b = y
    this.c = w
    this.h = h
  }
  
  adsfads (a, b, c, d) {
    this.a = a
    this.b = b
    this.c = c
  }
}

var bigarray = []
for (t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
  var newobj = new cobj(t, t, t, t);
  bigarray.push(newobj);
}
for (t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
  var localobj = bigarray[t];
  localobj.adsfads(t + 1, t + 1, t + 1, t + 1);
  console.log(localobj)
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

---

The ES5 equivalent would be something like

```js
function cobj(x, y, w, h) {
  this.a = x
  this.b = y
  this.c = w
  this.h = h
}

cobj.prototype.adsfads = function(a, b, c, d) {
  this.a = a
  this.b = b
  this.c = c
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized as I understand it at this point I needed the class and the constructor, it didn't seem to get there using the other syntax.